# Vue.js Tutorials: Conditonals in Vue.js not working - Property or method is not defined

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am trying to follow [this tutorial](https://scrimba.com/scrim/cEQe4SJ?pl=pXKqta) and copied the code. The only thing I changed is the location of index.js, what should not be the issue, as the hello world tutorial worked fine. The consoles outputs the following:

```
[Vue warn]: Property or method "seen" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property. See: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Declaring-Reactive-Properties.(found in <Root>)
```

So my questions if, if there is anything wrong with this code from the index.js file:

```
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    seen: true
  }
})
```

or is there something wrong with the html file (inserted into a markdown file, thus the title part)

```
---
title: vue
---
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div id="app">
            <span v-if="seen">Now you see me</span>
        </div>

        <script src="vue/index.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

It is probably a simple mistake, but I have been fiddling around for two hours. It would be great if someone could help me out.

Comment: please provide part that raises this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using CDN your code should be like :

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
</head>
<div id="app">
  <span v-if="seen">Now you see me</span>

</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    data() {
      return {
        seen: true,
      };
    },
  });
</script>
<style>

</style>

</html>
```

you define data as a function that returns object.

Comment: Your example works, but it still does not work with an external js file. I copied `new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      seen: true,
    };
  },
});` into index.js, which still outputs the above mentioned error

Comment: try out `<script src="./vue/index.js"></script>` or `<script src="/vue/index.js"></script>`

Comment: The path is right I guess. Otherwise the console outputs `GET http://localhost/vue/index.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)`

Comment: It finally worked. I dont know why, but my browser did not load the latest index.js file. The web inspector was still showing my old "hello world" example. I changed the browser and the recent index.js file loaded! Thanks!

Comment: you're welcome, which browsers did you used?

Comment: I was testing it on Edge. It still does not load the right index.js file. Weird.

Answer (score 2):

First, we don't write `data` like this but like this `data(){return { seen:true };}`

And this code works:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <span v-if="seen">Now you see me</span>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "App",
  data() {
    return {
      seen: true,
    };
  },
};
</script>

<style>
</style>
```

Something cool with Vuejs is that HTML JS and CSS part is on the same page.
And for the HTML part, it's just an `<template>` and inside add direct the `<div>` without `<body>`

Comment: `---
title: vue
---
<html>
    <head>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
    </head>

    <template>
      <div id="app">
        <span v-if="seen">Now you see me</span>
      </div>
    </template>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    export default {
      name: "App",
      data() {
        return {
          seen: true,
        };
      },
    };
    </script>

    <style>
    </style>

</html>` This code produces the error vue:143 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'.